# Is it haraam to watch porn with ones wife to learn things?

Tags: sex, education

Salam !

I am here to ask whether it is permissable to watch porn for an educational purpose.

Me and my wife have done this 1 time before, and it has shown to help a little bit with the fantasising part of sex. My wife is extremely bold and likes to try new things, and she loves indulging in sex. Please help with this.

I also have some other questions

Is it haraam for a woman to be dominant in sex. My wife loves to dominate me and takes the lead. Also, Do I have to have sex until my wife climaxes? Men climax faster, and we often get tired after doing so.

Lastly, this question has elements from my first question. In schools in the UK as part of a subject named PSHE kids (age 10 (year 5) to ages 16 ( year 11)). Many parents struggle to teach children about sex in Islam, and Madrasahs do not feel comfort in doing so. Schools and what many people resort to, porn, and the only way young ones learn about sex and the beauty of it. So, is it permissible to watch such sexual videos such as a woman giving birth or a animation of sex to teach small children about sex?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the ruse of shaytan to push you to do something haram.
Don’t watch porn at all. It is haram and even if you watch it you won’t learn anything incredibly important. And there are many halal and good alternatives to porn.
Have a good time with your wife and don’t do anything haram. It’s absolutely not haram for a woman to be dominant in sex.

Answer (score 0):

Salam to you!

It's a very nice question to be asked. You, dude, know that god says in qu'ran "don't try to approach adultry ". It's apparent that watching naked women by you and naked men by your wife comes under this subject. Also this may reduce the sense of satisfaction for both of you toward one another.

If you are talking about learning new positions, new acts, it's no haram at all, I think there is a big number of videos on youtube made by specialists who are takling such sort of thing  which also may help children learn better about sex.

```
You're right about reaching the climax for women. I would say what a doctor was once talking about. She said " for men to reach the climax along with their women, they can excite women upper part , the sexual cells in their breasts, before the process of the final part "

Children shall learn about sex when they are about to be teenagers but not by watching such videos which excites them in their early age. This can be carried out by parents and school specialists.
```

Comment: Please cite sources for your answer